# django channels asyncio trouble running task in order

Tags: python, python-asyncio, django-channels

I'm struggling to get some code to work using `asyncio`. I'm very new to it. So new to it, that I don't know how to properly figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I am using Django Channels to run an `AyncJsonWebsocketConsumer` which I connect to via websockets from the client application. I used websockets because I need bidirectional communication. I'm creating a printing process where I start a series of long running actions, but I need the ability to pause, stop, etc. I had this all working when I was using `asyncio.sleep(x)` to mock my long running task (the `print_layer` method). When I tried adding my RPC to a queue inplace of the `asyncio.sleep` it stopped working as expected.

```py
class Command(Enum):
    START = 'start_print'
    PAUSE = 'pause_print'
    STOP = 'stop_print'
    CANCEL = 'cancel_print'
    RESET = 'reset_print'

class State(Enum):
    NOT_STARTED = 0
    STARTING = 1
    RUNNING = 2
    PAUSED = 3
    STOPPED = 4
    COMPLETE = 5
    ERROR = 500

class PrintConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.status = State.NOT_STARTED
        self.publisher = Publisher()
        self.print_instruction = None
        self.current_task = None
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.loop.set_debug(enabled=True)

    @property
    def running_task(self):
        return self.current_task is not None and not self.current_task.done() and not self.current_task.cancelled()

    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        self.status = State.STOPPED

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        response = json.loads(text_data)
        event_cmd = response.get('event', None)
        
        if Command(event_cmd) == Command.START:
            if self.status == State.NOT_STARTED:
                sting_uuid = response.get('sting_uuid', None)
                try:
                    await asyncio.wait_for(self.initialize_print(sting_uuid), timeout=10)  # WARNING: this is blocking
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    self.status = State.ERROR
            self.status = State.RUNNING
            if not self.running_task:
                # it would only have a running task in this situation already if someone starts/stops it quickly
                self.current_task = asyncio.create_task(self.resume_print())
        elif Command(event_cmd) == Command.PAUSE:
            self.status = State.PAUSED
        elif Command(event_cmd) == Command.STOP:
            if self.running_task:
                self.current_task.cancel()
        elif Command(event_cmd) == Command.RESET:
            self.status = State.NOT_STARTED
            self.print_instruction = None
            if self.running_task:
                self.current_task.cancel()
            self.current_task = None
            await self.send(json.dumps({ 'message': []}))
        
    async def initialize_print(self, uuid):
        stingfile = await get_file(uuid)
        # This is just an iterator that returns the next task to do
        # hence I use "next" in the resume_print method
        self.print_instruction = StingInstruction(stingfile)


    async def resume_print(self):
        try:
            while self.status == State.RUNNING:
                await self.send(json.dumps({ 'message': self.print_instruction.serialized_action_status}))
                await asyncio.sleep(.2) # It works with this here only
                try:
                    action = next(self.print_instruction)  # step through iterator
                except StopIteration:
                    self.status = State.COMPLETE
                    break;

                # can't seem to get this part to work
                await self.print_layer(action)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            # TODO: Add logic here that will send a command out to stop pumps and all motors.
            self.status = State.STOPPED
    
    async def print_layer(self, instruction):
        print_command = instruction['instruction']
        # this publishes using RPC, so it holds until I get a response.
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(self.publisher.publish('pumps', json.dumps(print_command)), timeout=10)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            self.status = State.ERROR
        # when I used just this in the function, the code worked as expected
        # await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

I don't know where to begin when showing what I've tried... My "best" attempt, as I see it, was to turn the `print_layer` method into a thread so that it did not block execution using `asyncio.to_thread(print_layer)`.. but in many of the things I tried, it would not even execute.

The `self.print_instruction.serialized_action_status` returns the status of each step. My goal is to have it sending this before each long running task. This might look like...

```
# sending status update for each step to client
# running print_layer for first action
# sending status update for each step to client
# running print_layer for second action
...
# sending final update
```

Instead, I'm creating every single task at once, and it's sending the updates all at the end when I add the long running task, or a number of issues. I can get the long running task to run in order (seemingly), but the `send` won't actually send inbetween layer prints. I'd really appreciate some help.. thank you in advance.

Here is some simplified relevant code (doesn't handle connection loss, etc) for my publisher...

```py
class Publisher():
    def on_response(self, ch, method, props, body):
        """when job response set job to inactive"""

    async def publish(routing_key, msg):
        new_corr_id = str(uuid4())
        self.active_jobs[new_corr_id] = False
        self.channel.basic_publish(...)
        white not self.active_jobs[new_corr_id]:
            self._connection.process_data_events()
            sleep(.1)
```

---

I found a partial working hack.. if I add
`await asyncio.sleep(.1)` after my send command (i.e. like this)

```
await self.send(json.dumps({ 'message': self.print_instruction.serialized_action_status}))
await asyncio.sleep(.2)
```

then it appears to work how I want it to (minus ability to interrupt), and I'm able to still pause/start my process. Obviously I'd rather do this without a hack. Why does this code all of the sudden work where the status updates send out as expected after the `.2` asyncio sleep and not without? I also can not interrupt with a STOP command, which I don't understand. I would have expected the django channel to read the stop command, and then cancel the task that was running and force the `asyncio.CancelledError` in the `resume_print` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong.

I had been assuming that because I made a function a coroutine (put `async` in front of it), that the even loop would automatically wait while doing the io operations. That is absolutely not the case. In my case, this was here:

```
class Publisher():
    def on_response(self, ch, method, props, body):
        """when job response set job to inactive"""

    async def publish(routing_key, msg):
        new_corr_id = str(uuid4())
        self.active_jobs[new_corr_id] = False
        self.channel.basic_publish(...)
        white not self.active_jobs[new_corr_id]:
            self._connection.process_data_events()
            sleep(.1)
```

in the `publish` method. This example was using `pika` and doing a `basic_publish` to a direct exchange. This is not asynchronous, and was blocking the event loop. I switched my publisher to use `aio-pika` instead, and then once my `publish` command was made asynchronous, the event loop was no longer being blocked, and the code works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with changing one thing in the code :

```
    if Command(event_cmd) == Command.START:
        if self.status == State.NOT_STARTED:
            sting_uuid = response.get('sting_uuid', None)
            try:
                await asyncio.wait_for(self.initialize_print(sting_uuid), timeout=10)  # WARNING: this is blocking
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                self.status = State.ERROR
        self.status = State.RUNNING
        #--> This will always set it to running, as it is outside of the if statement. That will stop your stop problem
        #You might want to do this (see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) : 
            else:
                self.status = State.RUNNING
        if not self.running_task:
            # it would only have a running task in this situation already if someone starts/stops it quickly
            self.current_task = asyncio.create_task(self.resume_print())
    elif Command(event_cmd) == Command.PAUSE:
        self.status = State.PAUSED
    elif Command(event_cmd) == Command.STOP:
        if self.running_task:
            self.current_task.cancel()
    elif Command(event_cmd) == Command.RESET:
        self.status = State.NOT_STARTED
        self.print_instruction = None
        if self.running_task:
            self.current_task.cancel()
        self.current_task = None
        await self.send(json.dumps({ 'message': []}))
```

Further, could you complete it with the imports you are doing?

Did you check out this :

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

This might help you with getting the send option to do as you want.

Comment: Hi @Sneil, thank you for your time. I did spend a great deal of time going through asyncio's documentation. It came down to not understanding how the event loop works.